# Semantic segmentation to instance segmentation

Tags: image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

Having a mask from semantic segmentation I want to split it to list of non-overlapping instances masks(like an output from instance segmentation). Do you know some fast algorithm, approach, tool or library to do this? I have found one python library. But it is very slow. Naive python implementation will also be slow.

Comment: Can you specify the library? Maybe edit your question by including a link pointing to it.

Comment: Could you provide at least a sample image of the label to see if it's even feasible to do it?
Instance Segmentation to Semantic Segmentation is possible, but this is not a reversible operation unless you can separate the instances by using some morphological operation or trained object detector.